# Creating large number of datasets with h5py - Unable to register datatype atom (Can't insert duplicate key)

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I am attempting to store a large number of numpy structured array as datasets in a hdf5 file. 

For example,
f['tree1'] = structured_array1

.

.

f['tree60000'] = structured_array60000
(there are ~ 60000 trees),

About 70% of the way into reading the file, I get the error 
RuntimeError: Unable to register datatype atom (Can't insert duplicate key)

This problem occurs only for an ascii file that is very large (10e7 lines, 5gb). It does not occur if the file is around (10e6 lines, 500mb). It also does not occur if I take out the datatype and just store as a numpy array of strings.

I can fix this problem if I stop reading halfway into the file, close my terminal, open it again, and continuing reading the file starting from halfway to the end (I save the line number I ended on). I tried opening and closing the hdf5 file in the python function itself, but this did not work.

```
dt = [
('scale', 'f4'), 
('haloid', 'i8'), 
('scale_desc', 'f4'), 
('haloid_desc', 'i8'), 
('num_prog', 'i4'), 
('pid', 'i8'), 
('upid', 'i8'), 
('pid_desc', 'i8'), 
('phantom', 'i4'), 
('mvir_sam', 'f4'), 
('mvir', 'f4'), 
('rvir', 'f4'), 
('rs', 'f4'), 
('vrms', 'f4'), 
('mmp', 'i4'), 
('scale_lastmm', 'f4'), 
('vmax', 'f4'), 
('x', 'f4'), 
('y', 'f4'), 
('z', 'f4'), 
('vx', 'f4'), 
('vy', 'f4'), 
('vz', 'f4'), 
('jx', 'f4'), 
('jy', 'f4'), 
('jz', 'f4'), 
('spin', 'f4'), 
('haloid_breadth_first', 'i8'), 
('haloid_depth_first', 'i8'), 
('haloid_tree_root', 'i8'), 
('haloid_orig', 'i8'), 
('snap_num', 'i4'), 
('haloid_next_coprog_depthfirst', 'i8'), 
('haloid_last_prog_depthfirst', 'i8'), 
('haloid_last_mainleaf_depthfirst', 'i8'), 
('rs_klypin', 'f4'), 
('mvir_all', 'f4'), 
('m200b', 'f4'), 
('m200c', 'f4'), 
('m500c', 'f4'), 
('m2500c', 'f4'), 
('xoff', 'f4'), 
('voff', 'f4'), 
('spin_bullock', 'f4'), 
('b_to_a', 'f4'), 
('c_to_a', 'f4'), 
('axisA_x', 'f4'), 
('axisA_y', 'f4'), 
('axisA_z', 'f4'), 
('b_to_a_500c', 'f4'), 
('c_to_a_500c', 'f4'), 
('axisA_x_500c', 'f4'), 
('axisA_y_500c', 'f4'), 
('axisA_z_500c', 'f4'), 
('t_by_u', 'f4'), 
('mass_pe_behroozi', 'f4'), 
('mass_pe_diemer', 'f4')
]

def read_in_trees(self):
    """Store each tree as an hdf5 dataset.
    """  
    with open(self.fname) as ascii_file:
        with h5py.File(self.hdf5_name,"r+") as f:
            tree_id = ""  
            current_tree = []
            for line in ascii_file:
                if(line[0]=='#'): #new tree
                        arr = np.array(current_tree, dtype = dt)
                        f[tree_id] = arr
                        current_tree = []
                    tree_id = line[6:].strip('\n')
                else: #read in next tree element
                    current_tree.append(tuple(line.split()))
    return
```

Error:

```
/Volumes/My Passport for Mac/raw_trees/bolshoi/rockstar/asciiReaderOne.py in read_in_trees(self)
    129                             arr = np.array(current_tree, dtype = dt)
    130                             # depth_sort =  arr['haloid_depth_first'].argsort()
--> 131                             f[tree_id] = arr
    132                             current_tree = []
    133                         first_line = False

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/_objects.so in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2458)()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/_objects.so in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2415)()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.pyc in __setitem__(self, name, obj)
    281 
    282         else:
--> 283             ds = self.create_dataset(None, data=obj, dtype=base.guess_dtype(obj))
    284             h5o.link(ds.id, self.id, name, lcpl=lcpl)
    285 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.pyc in create_dataset(self, name, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
    101         """
    102         with phil:
--> 103             dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
    104             dset = dataset.Dataset(dsid)
    105             if name is not None:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.pyc in make_new_dset(parent, shape, dtype, data, chunks, compression, shuffle, fletcher32, maxshape, compression_opts, fillvalue, scaleoffset, track_times)
    124 
    125     if data is not None:
--> 126         dset_id.write(h5s.ALL, h5s.ALL, data)
    127 
    128     return dset_id

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/_objects.so in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2458)()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/_objects.so in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2415)()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5d.so in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.write (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/h5d.c:3260)()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5t.so in h5py.h5t.py_create (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:15314)()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5t.so in h5py.h5t.py_create (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:14903)()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5t.so in h5py.h5t._c_compound (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:14192)()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5t.so in h5py.h5t.py_create (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:15314)()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5t.so in h5py.h5t.py_create (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:14749)()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5t.so in h5py.h5t._c_float (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:12379)()

RuntimeError: Unable to register datatype atom (Can't insert duplicate key)
```

Comment: Sounds like `tree_id` is repeated in the `ascii_file`.  If there aren't real duplicates maybe there's some sort of truncation.  Or some `c` code in the interface is indexing with small ints.  Is there some sort of `h5py` `flush` method?  I.e. tell it, save the data sets that you have, and start over?

Comment: Your 10e6/7 error range is close to `2*32`, which could produce problems on 32bit machines.

Comment: There are no duplicate trees. The hdf5 data is saved when I close the terminal and start again midway, but I am looking for a less hacky solution.

Answer (score 2):

Do you get an error stack? An indication of where in the code the error is produced?

You report: `error RuntimeError: Unable to register datatype atom (Can't insert duplicate key)`

In /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/datatype.py

```
class Datatype(HLObject):
    # Represents an HDF5 named datatype stored in a file.
    # >>> MyGroup["name"] = numpy.dtype("f")
    def __init__(self, bind):
        """ Create a new Datatype object by binding to a low-level TypeID.
```

I'm throwing out a guess here.  Your `dt` has 57 terms. I suspect that each time you add a `tree` to the file, it registers each field as a new `datatype`.

```
In [71]: (57*10e7*.7)/(2**32)
Out[71]: 0.9289942681789397
```

70% of 57 * 10e7 is close to 2*32.  If Python/numpy uses int32 as the dtype id, then you could be hitting this limit.

We'd have to dig around more in either the `h5py` or `numpy` code to find who emits this error message.

By adding an array to the file with:

```
f[tree_id] = arr
```

you are putting each array in a Dataset in a new `Group`.  If each Dataset has a dtype, or datatype for each field of array, you could easily get 2*32 datatypes.

If on the other hand you could store multiple `arr` to a Group or Dataset, you might avoid this registration of thousands of datatypes.  I'm not familiar enough with `h5py` to suggest how you do that.

---

I wonder if this sequence works to reuse the datatype for multiple datasets:

```
dt1=np.dtype(dt)
gg= f.create_group('testgroup')
gg['xdtype']=dt1
# see h5py.Datatype doc
xdtype=gg['xdtype']
x=np.zeros((10,),dtype=xdtype)
gg['tree1']=x
x=np.ones((10,),dtype=xdtype)
gg['tree2']=x
```

Following the `Datatype` doc I am trying to register a named datatype, and use it for each of the datasets added to the group.

```
In [117]: isinstance(xdtype, h5py.Datatype)
Out[117]: True
In [118]: xdtype.id
Out[118]: <h5py.h5t.TypeCompoundID at 0xb46e0d4c>
```

So if I am reading `def make_new_dset` correctly, this bypasses the `py_create` call.

Comment: I posted the error message. I also found out that the code stops after creating ~48000 datasets. Each dataset stores its own datatype.

Comment: typically how many elements (rows) are there in each `tree` dataset?

Comment: I think I've found a way of registering the `dtype`, so it doesn't create a new set for each `tree`.

Comment: I tried your code for reusing the datatype but still came up with the same error.

Comment: It seems to be running out of dset_ids rather than dtype ids, but still the problem only occurs when I specify the dtype.