# h5py - Adding padding to dataset

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I have to generate hdf5 files that match a certain format. Part of that format requires padding between certain fields. I have successfully placed padding between fields by setting the offset of the field after the padding, but I am having trouble getting h5py to add padding to the end of a dataset. I have been trying to do this by setting the itemsize of the dtype to account for the padding. For example:

```
import h5py as h5py
import numpy as np

dt = np.dtype({'names': ['a', 'b'], 'formats': ['uint8', 'uint8'], 'itemsize': 3})
file = h5.File('test.h5', 'w')
dset = file.create_dataset("dset1", dtype=dt)
file.close()
```

Which means the size should be 3 bytes. However:

```
>>> dset.dtype.itemsize
2
```

This seems to be an issue with how h5py handles dtypes. Does anyone know any way around this?

EDIT: So it turns out that this isn't an issue. When the dataset is created it doesn't update it dtype representation properly. The actual h5t size is correct though.

Comment: A previous SO on `h5py` and `structured` dtypes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190573/creating-large-number-of-datasets-with-h5py-unable-to-register-datatype-atom; also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784482/h5py-compound-datatypes-and-scale-offset-in-the-compression-pipeline

Comment: Thanks for the links. It helps get closer but not quite. The issue seems inherent in converting from a numpy dtype to an h5py Datatype. Still can't figure out how to get the new Datatype to be the correct size.

Comment: How about a dummy single byte field?

Comment: That's actually what we are trying to get rid of. We have those in several places which does not conform to spec. We know HDF5 can support padding, even at the end of a dataset. Getting Python to build these files to spec is the hard part.

Comment: I'd have to dig into the `h5py` code to see how it translates the `numpy` dtype into a HDF5 spec.  Maybe it ignores the `itemsize` attribute. If my memory is correct, `h5py` uses a `Cython` layer to interface with the C++ code.  I haven't used the dtype `itemsize` parameter, and only used `offset` a few times.

Comment: Just make sure we are on the same page, my `h5py` version is `'2.6.0'`.

Comment: Mine is 2.7.0. They implemented an important change in the new version related to padding so this was necessary for me. I don't know if it matters for this issue though.

Comment: The at-fault code appears to be here: https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/h5py/_hl/dataset.py#L34-L47. It should be calling H5Tget_size and passing the result as 'itemsize' to numpy.dtype.